# Sailsjs add one to many association to a model during beforeCreate

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to give a default association from a user to a pet, whenever a new User created.

Model:: User.js

```
    var User = {
        attributes: {
            name: {type: 'string'},
            // Add a One Way Relation to pet model
            pets: {
                collection: 'pet'
            },
        },

      /*** This did not work ***/
      beforeCreate: function (user, next) {
        var defaultPet = {name: 'Default Pet 1'};
        Pet.find(defaultPet).exec(function(err, pet) {
            user.name = "BEFORECREATE",
            user.pets = pet[0].id;
            next();
        });
      },

    }

module.exports = User;
```

However when a new record is created the user.pet is [ ], but user.name is changed to "BEFORECREATE".

How do I get user.pets = [{name: 'Default Pet 1'}] automatically for the new user created?

Or is there a better place for setting such defaults?

----- UPDATE: More info

I am using sails-disk currently.

Model: Pet.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add associations to a model in a lifecycle callback like `beforeCreate`.  Currently, Waterline looks for and processes "nested models" like these *before* lifecycle callbacks run, so by the time `beforeCreate` is called it's too late.  The simplest solution would be to create a `User.createUser` class method that wraps the logic you want:

```
  createUser: function(data, cb) {
    // If there are already pets specified, just use those
    if (data.pets) {return User.create(data).exec(cb);}
    // Otherwise look up the default pet
    Pet.findOne({name:"Default Pet 1"}).exec(function(err,pet) {
      // Return in case of error
      if (err) {return cb(err);}
      // Assuming the default pet exists, attach it
      if (pet) {
        console.log("SETTING DEFAULT PET", pet.id);
        data.pets = [pet.id];
      }
      // Create the pet
      return User.create(data).exec(cb);
    });
  }
```

A few notes:

1. In your example you were setting `pets` directly to an ID, but since it's a collection you must set it to an array.
2. If you're using the `sails-disk` adapter, you'll need to set `schema: true` in your model for this to work.
3. The new `User` model you get back will *not* be populated; you'll have to do a `find` with a `populate('pets')` with the new User ID to get the pet data attached.

Comment: Personnally I added a temporary field to my model, put there the ids i needed, and went to the afterCreate to put the ids of the temporary field to the collection one.